# Последовательный спаун блоков пути и рандомный спаун видов препятствий внутри них

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как это реализовать? Приложил скрипт, который сейчас рандомно генерирует блоки БЕЗ препятствий.

Задача:

1. Последовательная генерация блоков дороги из массива. Т.е на что заменить `Random.Range`?
2. Случайная генерация препятствий из массива на каждом блоке в определенных координатах. Если считать от центра каждого блока, то, допустим, будет z = -1, 0, 1.

```
public class RoadSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] RoadBlockPrefabs; 

    float startBlockXPos; // позиция для старт блока 
    int blocksCount = 4; // сколько изначально блоков генерируется
    float blockLength = 0;

    public Transform PlayerTransf;
    List<GameObject> CurrentBlocks = new List<GameObject>();

    public Vector3 startPlayerPos;

    public void Start()
    {
        startBlockXPos = PlayerTransf.position.x + 20f;
        blockLength = 80; // длина

        StartGame();
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        PlayerTransf.GetComponent<MovePlayer>().ResetPosition(); // вызываем метод  старт позиции

        foreach (var go in CurrentBlocks) 
            Destroy(go);

        CurrentBlocks.Clear(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < blocksCount; i++) 
            SpawnBlock();
    }

    public void LateUpdate()
    {
        CheckForSpawn();
    }

    public void CheckForSpawn()
    {
        // если игрок находится дальше на...., чем текущий блок
        if (CurrentBlocks[0].transform.position.x - PlayerTransf.position.x < -60)  
        {
            SpawnBlock();
            DestroyBlock();
        }
    }

    public void SpawnBlock()
    {
        GameObject block = Instantiate(RoadBlockPrefabs[Random.Range(0, RoadBlockPrefabs.Length)], transform);
        Vector3 blockPos;

        if (CurrentBlocks.Count > 0)   
            blockPos = CurrentBlocks[CurrentBlocks.Count - 1].transform.position + new Vector3(blockLength, 0, 0);

        else
            blockPos = new Vector3(startBlockXPos, 0, 0);

        block.transform.position = blockPos;

        CurrentBlocks.Add(block);
    }

    public void DestroyBlock()
    {
        Destroy(CurrentBlocks[0]);
        CurrentBlocks.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Иллюстрация как пример.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Последовательная генерация.

```
for (int i = 0; i < blocksCount; i++) { SpawnBlock(); }
...
public void SpawnBlock () {
    int bnum = CurrentBlocks.Count%RoadBlockPrefabs.Length;
    GameObject block = Instantiate(RoadBlockPrefabs[bnum], transform);
}
```

2 Тупо прикрепить препятствие к блоку.

```
barrier.transorm.parent = CurrentBlocks[n].transform;
barrier.transorm.localPosition = new Vector3(-1, blockHeight*0.5f, 1);
```

Comment: Благодарю! Последовательность работает, но как вписать в метод CheckForSpawn() сам SpawnBlock? Компилятор ругается "The name 'i' does not exist in the current context" , если прописать SpawnBlock(i)

Comment: Поменял. Да, аргумент там был и не нужен.

Comment: именно рандомная генерация препятствий в  -1, 0, 1 по z

Comment: Ну очевидно вместо `n` и `blockHeight`, ты должен указывать свои значения.